# Unhandled Rejection (Error): ffmpeg.wasm can only run one command at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ffmpeg, webassembly

I am using FFMPEG WASM in my react project. I have multiple videos that I'm looping over and using the await ffmpeg.run() function to apply modifications to.
But in the loop, when one iteration ends, it starts the next iteration even before ffmpeg.run() has stopped working and it throws this error Unhandled
`Rejection (Error): ffmpeg.wasm can only run one command at a time`

How can I fix this error? I am using async await but they don't seem to fix

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zExhN.png)

Comment: I am facing the same issue here. I am using React and ffmpeg/core v0.11.0 and ffmpeg/ffmpeg v0.11.6. I am using async and await as well